# The command STOP doesn't close the action during mediaobject playback

Tags: actions-on-google

I have a serious issue. My action plays long mp3 audio clips. They are open with

```
conv.ask(new MediaObject({
        name: title,
        url: storia,
        description: autore,
        image: new Image({
            url: largeImageUrl,
            alt: title,
        }),
    }));
```

The problem is that when the user says "STOP" the action should interrupt the playback and close, with a greeting. And this is the behavior I've always had since few days ago. Even the simulator is working this way. 
But on real device, the "STOP" command simply interrupt the playback but with no additional feedback to the user, that may be lead to think he has quit but he is still in the action. He has to say "EXIT" to quit.

I have a Media Status - Cancel intent that has always worked.

```
app.intent('Media Status - cancel', (conv) => {
    conv.close(new SimpleResponse('OK See you next time!')); 
});
```

And, again, it works in the simulator, but not on the real device.

I wonder if something has recently been changed, from Google side, about MediaObject playback.

Any help?

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you defined your `Media Status - cancel` Intent in Dialogflow?

Answer (score 0):

This has been a long-standing bug with the MediaObject.